# .NET Console Application as Container on Azure - need to respond to ping? How?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core

My goal is to have a simple .NET console application run as Docker container on Azure. (Note: **not** ASP.NET, just a plain console app.)

A tutorial from Microsoft showing how to create a dockerized .NET console application can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=linux

I followed those steps and deployed the container to an Azure Web App for Containers.

Unfortunately this container seems to fail to respond to pings from the runtime:

> 2022-02-01T14:58:45.080Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup
> request for container app-console-test-westeurope_0_fd964f41. Elapsed
> time = 1798.626016 sec
>
> 2022-02-01T14:58:47.107Z ERROR - Container
> app-console-test-westeurope_0_fd964f41 for site
> app-console-test-westeurope did not start within expected time limit.
> Elapsed time = 1800.6529377 sec
>
> 2022-02-01T14:58:47.115Z ERROR -
> Container app-console-test-westeurope_0_fd964f41 didn't respond to
> HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for
> debugging.
>
> 2022-02-01T14:58:48.026Z INFO  - Stopping site
> app-console-test-westeurope because it failed during startup.

I even created the startup time to 1800 seconds to make sure it is not just starting slowly.

What I don't understand:

- Do I have to make those pings work or is this covered somewhere under the hood?
- Do I have to explicitly expose ports (80?) in my Dockerfile? Note that the linked tutorial from Microsoft does not do this.
- Do I have to explicitly spin up a web server (from my console application) to respond to pings? Or is this already covered by the base image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` from the tutorial?

My console application is basically a while loop doing stuff and never returning:

```
while (true)
{
    await CallSomeService();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

The Dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleTest.dll"]
```

Comment: These are presumably heartbeats of the App Service container orchestrator. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview), App Service is intended to host web applications. Maybe you could use Azure Container Instances (ACI) or Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) instead?

Comment: Console apps usually run to completion and usually don't listen for HTTP traffic. Does yours?

Comment: @CSharpRocks not intentionally. I was under the impression that hosting a console app as container should just work and never so much thought about the ping aspect. Also the base image for the container being "dotnet/aspnet" made me thought that some automagic is contained in the image. But as your questions start coming in the feeling that it "just works" is fading...

Comment: "automagic" it is not.  Simply create a new .NET Core webapp, package it in a container and you should be able to reach it using http.